# Server signed claim: REST Authentication without server side caching

Tags: java, rest, authentication, cryptography

I am moving my Java web application from a session based one to a RESTful one in order to reduce/eliminate memory footprint of a session.

The common approach being proposed for this is to have the server generate a token after authentication. The client stores this token locally and sends it with subsequent every request. The server maintains a lookup table for generated tokens to validate them. The lookup table is usually cached in memory as every request needs to be authenticated/authorized.

In my opinion, this approach is not fundamentally different from using the built-in Session mechanism of Java. It does gives you some flexibility in terms of load balancing and where you store the lookup tables etc. But it does not eliminate the need of allocating some amount of memory (either in RAM or in storage) per authenticated user on the server.

So I thought of this:

1. User sends credentials to server. Server verifies it and returns a
   signed payload - say a JSON object containing information like - the
   Access control list, token expiry time stamp etc
2. This JSON object and the server signature generated for that object are sent by the client to the server along with every request.
3. The JSON object is basically a **claim** stating *"I am so and so and I am entitled to access these resources"*. When the server receives this claim it generates a signature for it and compares it with the signature sent by the client along with the claim. If they match, then it means the claim was not tampered by the client and must have been generated by the server itself.
4. So the server can basically treat the claim as true and proceed from there.

The advantage with this scheme is that the server does not have to maintain a lookup table in memory nor does it have to hit the database for authentication/authorization for every request.

What do you think about this approach? Does this scheme have a name? Is there any library or framework that implements something like this?

I am aware that secrecy of server's private key becomes exceedingly important in this scheme. Also, revoking a granted token before it's expiry is not possible But these are separate problems with fairly simple workarounds.

Comment: "The JSON object is basically a claim stating "I am so and so and I am entitled to access these resources". The sever generates a signature for this claim and compares it with the signature sent by the client along with the claim." But you still need to keep somehow the json object data  in db or cash to generate signature on the server, am I right?

Comment: No, the JSON object is sent by the client with each request. The signature mechanism is used to verify that the client has not tampered the object.

Comment: Ok, seems, I've got the point. But how are you going to deal with log outs? Don't you need to track it?

Comment: This is for an app. So log out if any is infrequent. Small timeout say 1 hr means tokens expire within an hour. If you want to force an immediate logout then cache logged out usernames instead, that too for 1 hour max as tokens would expire after that any way. This has way lower memory footprint than caching  user ACL and other assorted things in memory.

If it is a client imitated logout, then client simply has to forget its token.

Comment: *initiated not imitated

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is revocation with this approach. When you issue a signed token, you will need a mechanism to revoke the authority given by that signature (in case of log out from a certain device, or detection of suspicious activity from a certain log in.) This could get you back to the case of needing to do a look up per access. This could be optimised for performance by distributing the revocation to the processing nodes, with the added complexity of distributing those black lists.

You will most probably also need to manage expiry, and with that, black lists should also be garbage collected when what they black list is expired as well.

With expiry, there arises the need to keep servers synchronised to a wall clock, which can definitely bring up more trouble.